# Empty variables in python

Tags: python-2.7

This snippet is from my Python for Biologists book:

```
genomic = open("genomic_dna.txt").read()
exons = open("exons.txt")
for line in exons:
    positions = line.split(',')
    start = int(positions[0])
    stop = int(positions[1])
    exons = genomic[start:stop]
    coding_seq = coding_seq + exon
    print("Coding sequence is: " + coding_seq)
```

According to the book, this should work, but when I run it, I get a name error "coding_seq is not defined."

As I understand it, python is a dynamic language, so I shouldn't have to explicitly declare coding_seq before I use it in my loop.  Why isn't this code working correctly?

Comment: This is off topic here but `exon` is never set. I don't know what `exons.txt` is supposed to contain (a gff file? fasta?) but presumably that line should have read `coding_seq = coding_seq + start` or something else that is actually defined.

Answer (score 2):

You need define coding_seq first

```
genomic = open("genomic_dna.txt").read()
exons = open("exons.txt")
coding_seq = ""
for line in exons:
    positions = line.split(',')
    start = int(positions[0])
    stop = int(positions[1])
    exons = genomic[start:stop]
    coding_seq = coding_seq + exon
    print("Coding sequence is: " + coding_seq)
```